# How to handle paste image from clipboard in the Macgap App

Tags: macos, webkit

The macgap is use Safari webkit, but it's not support Paste image from clipboard, also include Safari itself.

Is there any way to handle image from clipboard through Macgap source code?
Or handle image from clipboard through Safari?

Comment: I had implement a API to solved this.

Comment: You could answer your own question with how you solved this issue. It would help others.

Comment: @vik Thanks for your mention, I have give the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I write some objc code to supply a API to give Javascript the way to get pasted image data.

It's the PR I submit and the solution how JS access this API:

https://github.com/MacGapProject/MacGap1/pull/138

Comment: Thanks for the answer and also the pull-request. Hope it will be in the main branch soon.